# How to store Apache Ant property value in file

Tags: ant

I need to modify a (xml-)file from Apache Ant. "loadfile" task allows to load the file's content in a property. But how to store the property's value back to a file after its (property) modification?

Of course I could write custom task to perform this operation but I would like to know if there's some existing implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [echo](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) task.

```
<echo file="${fileName}" message="${xmlProperty}"/>
```

The [echoxml](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoxml.html) task might be of interest to you as well.

Answer (score 6):

Use [propertyfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) task. An example taken from ant manual:

```
<propertyfile file="my.properties">
  <entry  key="abc" value="${abc}"/>
</propertyfile>
```

This may be better than `echo` as it updates the properties file with a given value, while `echo` appends to or overwrites the whole file.