# Using apache ant commands to store value to excel cell

Tags: excel, ant, webtest

I was curious if it was possible to store values into excel spreadsheet cells? And if so, how would one go about completing this? I also have multiple values that I would like to store into the same excel sheet but in different cells (like A2 or B1).

For example, say that I have a value that I want to stick into cell A1, right now, I can actually using this command:

```
<echo append="true" file="file.xls" message="1" />
```

This will store "1" in cell A1 and if I ran the same command again, it would store "1" in cell A1 as well, just next to the original echo. But I want is to have another value that's added in a different cell.

I've looked at other stackoverflow posts about this topic and searched google, but I couldn't find an answer to my exact case. Please let me know if you have any better ideas, thanks.

Here are the links that I used:

[propertyfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html)

[other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262015/how-to-store-apache-ant-property-value-in-file)

Comment: I think you will find that your `echo` does not work. `xls` files have a complex format and you must use an API provided by Excel to manipulate them.

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is.... You asked for an ANT solution to store data in Excel.

Comment: I'm working on implementing your answer now, you might be on the something. In any case, I'm just trying to find an ant command that will store data into excel cells.

Comment: I just have to know... Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not a trivial file format to parse and write.

The following example demonstrates how to create a macro that writes an excel file:

```
<excelWrite file="target/workbook.xlsx" values="Hello,world"/>
```

The macro uses the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) java library.

## Example

Running the build will generate an excel file

```
├── build.xml
└── target
    └── workbook.xlsx
```

Additional notes:

- [Apache ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is automatically installed and used to manage 3rd party jar dependencies
- Using an embedded [groovy script](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) avoids the need to write and compile an ant task.

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

   <!--
   ==========
   Properties
   ==========
   -->
   <property name="build.dir" location="target"/>

   <available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/> 

   <!--
   ======
   Macros
   ======
   -->
   <macrodef name="excelWrite">
      <attribute name="file"/>
      <attribute name="values"/>
      <attribute name="sheetName" default="ANT demo"/>
      <sequential>
         <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path">
            <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="2.2.2" conf="default"/>
            <dependency org="org.apache.poi" name="poi-ooxml" rev="3.10-FINAL" conf="default"/>
         </ivy:cachepath>

         <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

         <groovy>
         import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
         import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
         import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper
         import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet
         import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row

         Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
         Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("@{sheetName}");
         CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();

         // Write data to a single row
         short rowpos = 0;
         short colpos = 0;
         Row row = sheet.createRow(rowpos);

         "@{values}".split(",").each {
            row.createCell(colpos++).setCellValue(helper.createRichTextString(it));
         }

         // Ensure parent directory exists
         def file = new File("@{file}")
         file.getParentFile().mkdirs()

         project.log "Writing Excel file: "+file
         file.withOutputStream {
             wb.write(it)
         }
         </groovy>
      </sequential>
   </macrodef>

   <!--
   =============
   Project setup
   =============
   -->
   <target name="install-ivy" description="Install ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
      <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
      <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>

      <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
   </target>

   <!--
   ==========
   Main logic
   ==========
   -->
   <target name="build" depends="install-ivy" description="Create an Excel file">
      <excelWrite file="${build.dir}/workbook.xlsx" values="Hello,world"/>
   </target>

   <!--
   ===============
   Project Cleanup
   ===============
   -->
   <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
      <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
   </target>

   <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
      <ivy:cleancache/>
   </target>

</project>
```