# How to open excel file using ant command?

Tags: java, excel, ant, apache-poi

I am new to ant and I am looking for a way to open an excel file via an ant command. Right now, my program runs in a way that I specify an Excel file I want to open on my local machine. However, I want it so that the user, when typing the ant command, can specify the location/name of the Excel file as a command line argument and open it up that way. I have looked around at different ant commands like ant exec but to my knowledge, it seems to only execute executables if you specify the location. I was looking at [Using Ant, how do I open a file in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696176/using-ant-how-do-i-open-a-file-in-a-browser) for hints but this seems to run an executable. Any ideas how to do so? If so, that would be great!

Comment: Why do you want to use ant for that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen As an end goal, I want to package up my whole project into a jar and then create a bash script executable so that if someone non-technical uses this program, if I tell them the correct location/name of the excel file, they can double click on the executable and it will simply run the jar for them without having them  learn how to run command line arguments and such.

Comment: Drop ant launching and just figure out how you invoke "start.exe" from your own java code

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727192/using-apache-ant-commands-to-store-value-to-excel-cell/22729674#22729674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **link** you've included in your question seems sufficient.

for opening the `Excel` file, this should work:

```
<exec executable="-path-of-excel-exe-" spawn="true">
    <arg value="${user_file}"/>
</exec>
```

`-path-of-excel-exe-` is the path to `EXCEL.EXE` on your sys. for eg, on my system, 
**"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"**

now, as for accepting the file location, i.e. `${user_file}` in our case, as a **command-line argument**, this should work:

```
ant -Duser_file="file location"
```

`-D<property_name>=<property_value>`   use value for given property, see [**HERE**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html). so, the `"property_name"` specified here can be used in you `.xml` file and the corresponding `"property_value"` will be substituted.