# store ANT regex in an excel file

Tags: regex, excel, ant, fileset

I am creating an ANT script for which I am using a fileset and a regex to get my file and to get an expression in that file.
I also need to store the expression in a spreadsheet, which I am not sure how to do it.
I have learned somewhere that I could use replaceregexp, but I am not sure how do I do that.

I have used target tasks to do the search for the file and expression.

Comment: Storing data in a spreadsheet from ANT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727192/using-apache-ant-commands-to-store-value-to-excel-cell/22729674#22729674

Comment: I understand this. But what I was looking for is a technique to store my regex results in an excel file. I already have a target. I now want to use regex results from that target in another target where I will be storing the excel file. Or I could also find regex and store in the excel file. Do you now understand my technique?

Answer (score 0):

ANT is not a programming language so this is not a trivial problem to solve. The following example uses:

- [groovy task](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Using+Ant+from+Groovy) implement the parsing logic
- [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to write the excel file
- [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage the 3rd party jar dependencies.

## Example

This is example counts the number of occurrences of the string "one" in the resources sub directory:

```
├── build.xml
├── resources
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   └── file3.txt
└── results.xlsx
```

Results are also written to an excel file "results.xlsx"

```
parse-files:
   [groovy] File:file1.txt Count:1
   [groovy] File:file2.txt Count:0
   [groovy] File:file3.txt Count:1
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="parse-files" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

  <available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/> 

  <target name="parse-files" depends="init" >
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="groovy.path"/>

    <fileset dir="resources" id="filesToParse" includes="*.txt"/>

    <groovy>
      import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
      import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
      import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper
      import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet
      import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row

      Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
      Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Regexp results");
      CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
      rowpos = 0

      project.references.filesToParse.each {
        def file    = it.file
        def content = file.text

        // Search file
        def findOneStr = content =~ /one/

        println "File:${file.name} Count:${findOneStr.count}"

        // Save to Excel row
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowpos++)
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(helper.createRichTextString(file.name));
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(findOneStr.count);
      }

      // Save excel file
      new File("results.xlsx").withOutputStream {
        wb.write(it)
      }
    </groovy>
  </target>

  <target name="init" depends="install-ivy" description="Resolve dependencies">
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="groovy.path">
      <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="2.4.3" conf="default"/>
      <dependency org="org.apache.poi" name="poi-ooxml" rev="3.10.1" conf="default"/>
    </ivy:cachepath> 
  </target>

  <target name="install-ivy" description="Install ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar"/>

    <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
  </target>

</project>
```