# How to write into excel file using ant script

Tags: ant

I have a excel file, with some column like this
Name          DateTime (if value datetime existing then do not thing)
Jonh          16/07/2015 9:30 (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm) => date in system
Jonh          16/07/2015 10:30

The question : are there any way to write some sciprt ant to update excel file with two properties : Name and DateTime
When i run script ant, it's could be write new next row 
Jond          16/07/2015 11:30
Thanks.

Comment: Jonh 16/07/2015 9:30 (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm) => date in system

Comment: Jonh 16/07/2015 10:30

Comment: two column : Name                 DateTime

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an Excel manipulation library such as [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) called from a custom task or a [JDBC driver for Excel](http://code.google.com/p/sqlsheet/), using the `SQL` task to update the XLS file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial problem to solve. The following example uses a groovy script leveraging Apache POI to read/write Excel files:

- [Using apache ant commands to store value to excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727192/using-apache-ant-commands-to-store-value-to-excel-cell/22729674#22729674)
- [store ANT regex in an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931649/store-ant-regex-in-an-excel-file/30000104#30000104)